# BigQuery - upload csv with schema autodetect via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I need to upload data to BigQuery from Drive.
I found these two explanations ([Upload CSV](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery), [BQ Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs)),

However, I don't want to define the schema everytime anew. In manual upload you can check the 'autodetect' but in the script I can't find how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `jobs.load` API, you are looking for the [`configuration.load.autodetect`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.autodetect) option. There should be a similarly named setting for Apps Script.

Comment: Correct, that is what I'm looking for. I found the API refer, but I do not know how to implement in the apps script

Comment: You just need to set it to true within the `load` object that is part of `configuration`, e.g. in the [loading CSV](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data) example and omit the `schema` from the `table` object.

Comment: hi @Ilja, welcome to Stackoverflow! If an answer is helpful to you and solves your problem consider accepting it and also voting it up :)!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Elliot.

Here is the updated request:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(csvFileId);

var data = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');

// Create the data upload job.
var job = {
        configuration: {
          load: {
            destinationTable: {
              projectId: projectId,
              datasetId: datasetId,
              tableId: tableId
              },
            skipLeadingRows: 1,
            autodetect: true
                 }
              }
           };

job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
```